# How to update to PHP 7.2.* in Google Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-5

I'm trying to install Laravel on Google Cloud Platform, but the PHP version is 5.6.30.

How can I  update it to the version PHP 7.2?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a standard or a flexible environment for your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the Standard or Flexible Runtime, different PHP versions are supported.

For the [Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#PHP_Selecting_the_PHP_runtime):

> App Engine runs your PHP web application using a PHP version [**5.5.34
>   interpreter**](http://php.net/releases/5_5_34.php). Note: On Linux you must also install PHP locally to run
>   your PHP apps.

To use PHP 7.2 in the [Flexible Enrironment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#choosing_a_php_version):

> By default, the PHP runtime uses PHP 7.2, but **you should explicitly
>   declare your PHP version in the composer.json** file to prevent your
>   application from being automatically upgraded when a new version of
>   PHP becomes available. The PHP versions 5.6.*, 7.0.*, and 7.1.* are
>   also supported.

So you include this in the composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "7.2.*"
    }
}
```

So if you're using Flexible Enrironment, set the PHP version following the above indications.

There is a [Community Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible) on how to run Laravel on Google App Engine Flexible Environment.